# Problem with a specific task using associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, associative-array

I've been stuck on this for the better part of the day and I'm out of ideas. I have an array like this:

```
    Array
(
    [rank] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Hideki'
            [1] => 'Rory'
            [2] => 'Sam'
    [money] => Array
        (
            [0] => '$100'
            [1] => '$200'
            [2] => '$500'          
        )
)
```

and I have the task to create an array with the following format from it:

```
       Array
    (
    [Hideki] => Array
        (
            [rank] => 1
            [money] => '$100'
        )
    [Rory] => Array
        (
            [rank] => 2
            [money] => '$200'
    [Sam] => Array
        (
            [rank] => 3
            [money] => '$500' 
        )
)
```

The catch is that 'rank' and 'money' have to be dynamic names

Comment: OK, so before we start proving answers to your homework, you need to tell us what you have tried so far. SO isnt just a Q&A site, its about guiding you to learn. Tell us what you have tried so far, along with code snippets :)

Comment: I get your comment and I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I'm literally out of any good ideas how to do it and I'm ashamed to share what I've tried so far :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple as that:

```
$new = [];

foreach($array['name'] as $key => $name) {
    $new[$name] = [
        'rank' => $array['rank'][$key],
        'money' => $array['money'][$key]
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem is that 'rank' and 'money' have to be dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

Run your first array through a foreach loop referencing only the "name" key and using key=>value pairs. Then reference the other keys from the first array when you build the new array, setting the value as the key to the second array.

You will need to first get the keys using `array_keys()` and use a nested foreach to loop through all the keys.

Example:

```
$keys1 = array_keys($array1);
foreach ($array1['name'] as $key => $value) {

  $val2 = array();
  foreach ($keys1 as $k){
    if ($k != 'name') $val2[$k] = $array1[$k][$key];
  }

  $array2[$value] = $val2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I need 'rank' and 'money' to be a dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

Little late but here my answear. My approach was to use the array_walk() function.

```
$array = [
    'rank' => [1,2,3],
    'name' => ['Hideki', 'Rory', 'Sam'],
    'money' => ['$100', '$200', '$500'],
];

$i = 0;
$newArray = [];
array_walk($array['name'], function($name) use (&$i, $array, &$newArray) {
    $newArray[$name] = ['rank'=> $array['rank'][$i], 'money' => $array['money'][$i]];
    $i++;

});
print_r($newArray);
```